# To Hide soft keyboard or virtual keyboard on loading the fragment

Tags: android-softkeyboard, android

There are  2 Edit text boxes in my fragment.Whenever this fragment is loaded by any activity the soft-keyboard appears on the screen thus covering half of the tablet screen.I want to hide the soft keyboard whenever my fragment is loaded by any activity.The soft-keyboard should appear only on clicking or tapping the edit text boxes.

Comment: do like this in your manifest.xml <activity 
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|stateHidden">

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Padma's comment will prevent the soft keyboard from EVER coming up in the application, which it doesn't sound like you want since you have EditText's that need to get their input from somewhere.

You could just close the soft keyboard for whichever EditText is on that view when it's loading:

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(findViewById(R.id.your_edit_text).getWindowToken(), 0);
```

Comment: Where do you put this code? I've tried in onCreateView() and onResume() but my EditText still grabs focus and opens the soft keyboard anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
              WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```

Answer (score 0):

For DialogFragment, you must remove focus from dialog instead only from the first EditText in the DialogFragment

```
this.getDialog().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);
```